# Program Octave in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, octave

Community,
probably my question seems really stupid, but maybe someone can guide me out of it. 
I installed everything as described here: https://adampash.com/how-to-install-octave/ 
and I can use Octave now in my terminal.

Is it possible to program Octave in the Xcode window to use the debugging options or something similar? Or is it just possible within the terminal?

I have used Google to find a solution. Unfortunately, I haven't found any that described my question.

Thank you
Paul

Comment: I think nowadays the easiest way to use Octave on Mac is http://octave-app.org/ I'm not sure if you have tried the GUI which includes tools for debugging

Comment: The ability to use XCode as a GUI interface for octave is not a goal for the project. The project provides its own GUI interface. If you've compiled octave correctly then the ability to launch the GUI should already be there. If running `octave` in the terminal does not launch octave with a GUI, try `octave --gui` or `octave --force-gui` (depending on your octave version)

Comment: Thanks for the props to Octave.app, @Andy! We're working hard to make it the best and easiest-to-use Octave distribution for Mac.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use Xcode. Xcode is for C, C++, Objective C, Swift, and other languages, but not Octave/Matlab. There's a reason for this: Xcode mostly supports compiled languages. Octave is an interpreted language with a heavy emphasis on interactive use. So a different sort of IDE is appropriate for it.

Octave has its own built-in GUI that is a sort of IDE. Use that instead of Xcode.

If you have Octave built with Qt support (which is the default for Homebrew and Octave.app installs on Mac), you can run it with `octave --gui` from the command line, or by double-clicking the Octave.app icon in `/Applications`.

The installation instructions in that link are out of date. There is no longer a `--with-x11` option for `brew install octave`, you no longer need X11 or XQuartz, and it's no longer in `homebrew/science`. Just run:

```
brew install octave
```

NOTE as of April 2019: The current Homebrew Octave is Octave 5.1.0, which has significant stability problems with its GUI. Instead, you probably want to use Octave 4.4.1 for now. To do that, download [Octave.app 4.4.1](http://octave-app.org/Download.html).